# Linux command-line PDF spellchecker

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line, spell-checker

I am looking for a command line tool that can spellcheck a PDF file, that can run on Linux. If possible, I would like the tool to be able to accept a custom dictionary.

I know [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7303/spell-and-grammar-checker-for-pdf-documents) already has answers suggesting graphical spellchecker tools, but I want one that can be used from the command line, so that I can automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to use `pdftotext` from poppler-utils to extract the text, and then use an existing command line spell-checker (`spell`, `ispell`, `aspell`, etc...) to check it.

Note that if you are generating the PDF, you are probably better off checking the source of that generation, as words are liable to be bro- ken by being formatted in a PDF.